# traceur conversion from ECMA6 to ECMA5 not working

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, traceur

I followed a tutorial in order to learn how traceur compiler converts ECMA6 to ECMA5.

Following is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello world!</title>

    <script src="https://traceur-compiler.googlecode.com/git/bin/traceur.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="https://traceur-compiler.googlecode.com/git/src/bootstrap.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
     <h1 id="message">This content is going to change</h1>
    <script type="text/traceur">
      class Greeter {
        constructor(message) {
          this.message = message;
        }

        greet() {
          let element = document.querySelector('#message');
          element.innerHTML = this.message;
        }
      };

      let greeter = new Greeter('Helllllllo, world!');
      greeter.greet();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But the content in `h1` tag does not change when I load the page in firefox or chrome. what is the issue ehre?

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem?

Comment: changed the script type to "module" but did not work, also checked the console of the browser for any errors, and there wasn't

Answer (score 0):

okay seems like there was a problem with the script url. this worked for me after following a different tutorial in github.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello world!</title>

    <script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/bin/traceur.js"></script>
    <script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/src/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
     <h1 id="message">This content is going to change</h1>
    <script type="module">
      class Greeter {
        constructor(message) {
          this.message = message;
        }

        greet() {
          let element = document.querySelector('#message');
          element.innerHTML = this.message;
        }
      };

      let greeter = new Greeter('Helllllllo, world!');
      greeter.greet();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also it worked with    `<script type="text/traceur">`